# R: Perform regression with rolling data

Tags: r, dplyr, regression, lm, rolling-computation

I have a large panel data set with daily data. I would like to perform a linear regression with a rolling time window to find out the daily alpha (Intercept).
I choose a rolling time window of 250 days per entity (Name). However, already when I have at least 30 days I start running the regression by just using first 30 observations, then 31, 32 etc. until I reach 250.

My data looks like this (just to show you, my real data has over 1000 observations per group and over 200 groups):

```
structure(list(Name = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C"), Date = c("2018-08-01", 
"2018-08-02", "2018-08-03", "2018-08-06", "2018-08-07", "2018-08-08", 
"2018-08-09", "2018-08-10", "2018-08-13", "2018-08-14", "2018-08-16", 
"2018-08-17", "2018-08-20", "2018-08-21", "2018-08-22", "2018-08-23", 
"2018-08-24", "2018-08-27", "2018-08-28", "2018-08-29", "2018-08-30", 
"2018-08-31", "2018-09-03", "2018-09-04", "2018-09-05", "2018-09-06", 
"2018-09-07", "2018-09-10", "2018-09-11", "2018-09-12", "2018-09-13", 
"2018-09-14", "2018-09-17", "2018-09-18", "2018-09-19", "2018-09-20", 
"2018-09-21", "2018-09-24", "2018-09-25", "2018-09-26", "2018-09-27", 
"2018-09-28", "2018-10-01", "2018-10-02", "2018-10-03", "2018-10-04", 
"2018-10-05", "2018-10-08", "2018-10-09", "2018-10-10", "2018-10-11", 
"2018-10-12", "2018-10-15", "2018-10-16", "2018-10-17", "2018-10-18", 
"2018-10-19", "2018-10-22", "2018-10-23", "2018-10-24", "2018-10-25", 
"2018-10-26", "2018-10-29", "2018-10-30", "2018-10-31", "2018-11-02", 
"2018-11-05", "2018-08-01", "2018-08-02", "2018-08-03", "2018-08-06", 
"2018-08-07", "2018-08-08", "2018-08-09", "2018-08-10", "2018-08-13", 
"2018-08-14", "2018-08-16", "2018-08-17", "2018-08-20", "2018-08-21", 
"2018-08-22", "2018-08-23", "2018-08-24", "2018-08-27", "2018-08-28", 
"2018-08-29", "2018-08-30", "2018-08-31", "2018-09-03", "2018-09-04", 
"2018-09-05", "2018-09-06", "2018-09-07", "2018-09-10", "2018-09-11", 
"2018-09-12", "2018-09-13", "2018-09-14", "2018-09-17", "2018-09-18", 
"2018-09-19", "2018-09-20", "2018-09-21", "2018-09-24", "2018-09-25", 
"2018-09-26", "2018-09-27", "2018-09-28", "2018-10-01", "2018-10-02", 
"2018-10-03", "2018-10-04", "2018-10-05", "2018-10-08", "2018-10-09", 
"2018-10-10", "2018-10-11", "2018-10-12", "2018-10-15", "2018-10-16", 
"2018-10-17", "2018-10-18", "2018-10-19", "2018-10-22", "2018-10-23", 
"2018-10-24", "2018-10-25", "2018-10-26", "2018-10-29", "2018-10-30", 
"2018-10-31", "2018-11-02", "2018-11-05", "2018-08-01", "2018-08-02", 
"2018-08-03", "2018-08-06", "2018-08-07", "2018-08-08", "2018-08-09", 
"2018-08-10", "2018-08-13", "2018-08-14", "2018-08-16", "2018-08-17", 
"2018-08-20", "2018-08-21", "2018-08-22", "2018-08-23", "2018-08-24", 
"2018-08-27", "2018-08-28", "2018-08-29", "2018-08-30", "2018-08-31", 
"2018-09-03", "2018-09-04", "2018-09-05", "2018-09-06", "2018-09-07", 
"2018-09-10", "2018-09-11", "2018-09-12", "2018-09-13", "2018-09-14", 
"2018-09-17", "2018-09-18", "2018-09-19", "2018-09-20", "2018-09-21", 
"2018-09-24", "2018-09-25", "2018-09-26", "2018-09-27", "2018-09-28", 
"2018-10-01", "2018-10-02", "2018-10-03", "2018-10-04", "2018-10-05", 
"2018-10-08", "2018-10-09", "2018-10-10", "2018-10-11", "2018-10-12", 
"2018-10-15", "2018-10-16", "2018-10-17", "2018-10-18", "2018-10-19", 
"2018-10-22", "2018-10-23", "2018-10-24", "2018-10-25", "2018-10-26", 
"2018-10-29", "2018-10-30", "2018-10-31", "2018-11-02", "2018-11-05"
), `Return-RF` = c(0.02, 0.3, 0.425, 0.56, -0.04, -0.246, 0.425, 
0.56, -0.04, 0.425, 0.56, -0.04, 0.56, 0.425, 0.56, -0.04, -1.265791457, 
0.118560063, 1.376111562, -0.729104746, -1.355130661, 1.158722853, 
1.351227849, 0.88999491, 0.614812405, 0.437523454, 0.388822079, 
0.004467408, -0.000544858, -1.265791457, 0.118560063, 1.376111562, 
-0.729104746, -1.355130661, 1.158722853, 1.351227849, 0.88999491, 
0.614812405, 0.437523454, 0.388822079, 0.004467408, -0.000544858, 
-0.729104746, -1.355130661, 1.158722853, 1.351227849, 0.88999491, 
0.614812405, -0.729104746, -1.355130661, 1.158722853, 1.351227849, 
0.88999491, 0.614812405, 0.425, 0.56, -0.04, 0.56, 0.425, 0.56, 
-0.04, 0.88999491, 0.614812405, 0.437523454, 0.388822079, 0.004467408, 
-0.000544858, -0.729104746, -1.355130661, 0.88999491, 0.614812405, 
0.437523454, 0.388822079, 0.004467408, -0.000544858, -0.729104746, 
-1.355130661, 0.88999491, 0.614812405, 0.437523454, 0.388822079, 
0.004467408, -0.000544858, -0.729104746, -1.355130661, 0.88999491, 
0.614812405, 0.437523454, 0.388822079, 0.004467408, -0.000544858, 
-0.729104746, -1.355130661, -1.355130661, -1.355130661, -0.729104746, 
-1.355130661, -0.729104746, -1.355130661, -0.000544858, -0.729104746, 
-1.355130661, -0.729104746, -1.355130661, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, 0.425, 0.56, -0.04, 0.56, 0.425, 0.56, -0.04, 0.56, 0.425, 
0.56, -0.04, 0.56, 0.425, 0.56, -0.04, NA, 0.425, 0.56, -0.04, 
0.56, 0.425, 0.425, 0.56, -0.04, 0.56, 0.56, -0.04, 0.56, 0.56, 
0.56, -0.04, 0.56, 0.56, -0.04, 0.56, 0.56, -0.04, -0.04, 0.56, 
0.425, 0.56, -0.04, 0.56, 0.56, -0.04, 0.56, 0.56, 0.56, -0.04, 
0.56, 0.56, 0.56, 0.56, -0.04, 0.56, -0.04, 0.56, 0.425, 0.56, 
-0.04, 0.56, -0.04, 0.56, 0.425, 0.56, -0.04, 0.56, -0.04, 0.56, 
0.425, 0.56, -0.04, -0.04, 0.56, 0.425, 0.56, -0.04, 0.56, 0.425, 
0.56, 0.56, 0.425, 0.56, 0.56, 0.56, 0.425, 0.56, -0.04, 0.56, 
0.425), `MKT-RF` = c(0.08, -0.03, 0.56, -0.22, -0.16, -0.44, 
0, -0.32, 0.15, 0.19, 0.15, 0.08, -0.03, 0.56, -0.22, -0.16, 
-0.44, 0, -0.32, 0.15, 0.08, -0.03, 0.56, -0.22, -0.16, -0.44, 
0, -0.32, 0.15, 0.19, 0.15, -0.1, -0.31, 0.08, -0.03, 0.56, -0.22, 
-0.16, -0.44, 0, 0.08, -0.03, 0.56, -0.22, -0.16, -0.44, 0, -0.32, 
0.15, 0.19, 0.15, -0.1, -0.31, 0.08, -0.03, 0.56, -0.22, -0.16, 
-0.44, 0, -0.32, 0.15, 0.19, 0.08, -0.03, 0.56, -0.22, -0.16, 
-0.44, 0, -0.32, 0.15, 0.08, -0.03, 0.56, -0.22, -0.16, -0.44, 
0, -0.32, 0.15, 0.19, 0.15, -0.1, -0.31, 0.08, -0.03, 0.56, -0.22, 
-0.16, -0.44, 0, -0.32, 0.15, 0.19, 0.15, 0.08, -0.03, 0.56, 
-0.22, -0.16, -0.44, 0, -0.32, 0.15, 0.19, 0.15, -0.1, -0.31, 
0.08, -0.03, 0.56, -0.22, -0.16, -0.44, 0, -0.32, 0.08, -0.03, 
0.56, -0.22, -0.16, -0.44, 0, -0.32, 0.15, 0.08, -0.03, 0.56, 
-0.22, -0.16, -0.44, 0, -0.32, 0.15, 0.19, 0.15, -0.1, -0.31, 
-0.08, -0.08, 0.08, -0.03, 0.56, -0.22, -0.16, -0.44, 0, -0.32, 
0.15, 0.19, 0.15, -0.1, -0.31, -0.08, 0.08, -0.03, 0.56, -0.22, 
-0.16, -0.44, 0, -0.32, 0.15, 0.19, 0.15, -0.1, -0.31, -0.08, 
0.08, -0.03, 0.56, -0.22, -0.16, -0.44, 0, -0.32, 0.15, 0.08, 
-0.03, 0.56, -0.22, -0.16, -0.44, 0, -0.32, 0.15, 0.19, 0.15, 
-0.1, -0.31, -0.08, -0.08, 0.08, -0.03, 0.56, -0.22, -0.16, -0.44, 
0, -0.32), SMB = c(0.28, 0.05, -0.27, 0.03, -0.3, 0.08, -0.03, 
0.56, -0.22, -0.16, -0.44, 0, -0.32, 0.15, 0.19, 0.15, -0.1, 
-0.31, -0.08, -0.08, 0.35, 0.73, -0.21, 0.19, 0.6, 0.02, 0.28, 
0.05, -0.27, 0.03, -0.3, 0.08, -0.03, 0.56, -0.22, -0.16, -0.44, 
0, -0.32, 0.15, 0.19, 0.15, -0.1, -0.31, -0.08, -0.08, 0.35, 
0.73, -0.21, 0.19, 0.6, 0.02, 0.28, 0.05, -0.27, 0.03, -0.3, 
0.08, -0.03, 0.56, -0.22, -0.16, -0.44, 0, -0.32, 0.15, 0.19, 
0.15, -0.1, -0.31, -0.08, -0.08, 0.35, 0.73, -0.21, 0.19, 0.6, 
0.02, 0.28, 0.05, -0.27, 0.03, -0.3, 0.08, -0.03, 0.56, -0.22, 
-0.16, -0.44, 0, -0.32, 0.15, 0.19, 0.15, -0.1, -0.31, -0.08, 
-0.08, 0.35, 0.73, -0.21, 0.19, 0.6, 0.02, 0.28, 0.05, -0.27, 
0.03, -0.3, 0.08, -0.03, 0.56, -0.22, -0.16, -0.44, 0, -0.32, 
0.15, 0.19, 0.15, -0.1, -0.31, -0.08, -0.08, 0.35, 0.73, -0.21, 
0.19, 0.6, 0.02, 0.28, 0.05, -0.27, 0.03, -0.3, 0.08, -0.03, 
0.56, -0.22, -0.16, -0.44, 0, -0.32, 0.15, 0.19, 0.15, -0.1, 
-0.31, -0.08, -0.08, 0.35, 0.73, -0.21, 0.19, 0.6, 0.02, 0.28, 
0.05, -0.27, 0.03, -0.3, 0.08, -0.03, 0.56, -0.22, -0.16, -0.44, 
0, -0.32, 0.15, 0.19, 0.15, -0.1, -0.31, -0.08, -0.08, 0.35, 
0.73, -0.21, 0.19, 0.6, 0.02, 0.28, 0.05, -0.27, 0.03, -0.3, 
0.08, -0.03, 0.56, -0.22, -0.16, -0.44, 0, -0.32, 0.15, 0.19, 
0.15, -0.1, -0.31, -0.08)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-201L))
```

My goal is to have an alpha (intercept) for each day (after the first 30 observations per group (Name). The dependent variable is Return-RF and the independent variables are MKT-RF and SMB.

I am very new to regressions with rolling time windows. Could someone help me?

I only came so far to have the code for the regression without a rolling time window. But this is not what I would like to achieve:

```
Regression <- Data %>%
  na.omit(Data$`Return - RF`) %>%
  group_by(`Name`) %>%
  do(tidy(lm((`Return - RF`) ~ `Mkt-RF` + SMB, data= .)))
```

Extract intercept:

```
Regression <- as.data.frame(Regression )
Intercept<- subset(Regression , term == "`Intercept`")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use rollapplyr to create the row number subsets to use and for each run the indicated function.  Note that unlike `do` within `mutate` dot (.) refers to all the rows in the data frame whereas `cur_data()` refers to the rows in the current group.

```
library(dplyr, exclude = c("filter", "lag"))
library(zoo)

Data %>%
  group_by(Name) %>%
  mutate(intercept = rollapplyr(1:n(), pmin(pmax(1:n(), 30), 250), function(ix)
    coef(lm(`Return-RF` ~ `MKT-RF` + SMB, cur_data(), subset=ix))[1], fill=NA)) %>%
  ungroup
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response! I tried to run the code with my real data. I have two questions: 1.) Where exactly do I account that I only use the rolling data of 250 days? So the 30 days are in the code but I would like that if I reach 250 days, the rolling windows stays 250 days. 2.) What exactly does fill=NA mean in this specific context?

Comment: That code was just taking the rolling intercept of the last 30 rows.  Have revised to specify  widths of `pmin(pmax(1:n(), 30), 250)` . `fill=NA` means that if it cannot complete a regression because there are fewer points available than the width that it should return NA for that point.  See ?rollapply for more info on the arguments to that function.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response and the adjustment in the answer.